# Excel conditional formatting to change entire row color

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have excel sheet which collect some numbers for each day. At end of each month I have row which will sum all numbers and show as an overview.date is in dd/mm/yyyy format on all cell except the one which shows the overview,
example:
Column A          Column B

```
1/01/2016           20
2/01/2016           1000
.
.
.
.
.
31/01/2016           10
Jan-2016            1030
```

As you can see after the last date in Jan it will create a row to show overview of the jan and it will continue for all month. I need to highlight the row which has overview using different background color.

I am able to highlight the Column A (where it will show Jan-2016 and so on) using below conditional formatting formula

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,$L$1:$L$12&"*"))
```

where L1 to L12 contains text : Jan, Feb, Mar .... Dec

But I am unable to find a way to highlight entire row instead of first cell in that cell.

Any idea here to achieve this ?

Comment: so... each month have a different background color?

Comment: no. it will have same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first... let's convert the date into text using:

```
=text(A1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

create a column for that formula.
Then, you can make conditional formatting using "text contain of...." Jan, Feb, Mar .... Dec. It make you easier to make the condition instead of "before-after date" or anything else.

Then.... to apply those rule for entire row, you can read it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/)

Hope it'll help.